# If I create an index to a table in sql server, a view which looks indexed table will be affected?

Tags: sql-server, view, indexing

I have a view and it looks a table. If I create an index for this table, view will be affected on this  index? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the view will be affected.

The view doesn't have an execution plan of itself, it will be included in the query that uses it, and a plan is made for the entire query, just as if you would paste the code from the view into the query.